# putting Nginx in front of Logstash?

Tags: nginx, logstash

When I search for `nginx logstash` , most talks about hadling nginx log with logstash.

I'm not doing that.

I'm thinking of putting Nginx in front of logstash.

Is it ok or beneficial to let logstash handle the http requests directly? (Because I couldn't find docs which puts Nginx in front of logstash, I think the term for this pattern is reverse proxy.. although I don't get why it's called `reverse` nor `proxy`)